# Recording video with Android

Tags: android, mp4, file-descriptor, mediarecorder

I need to process data that MediaRecorder provides when i recording video and then save into file as *.mp4. I have ParcelFileDescriptor and with that i send Recorder output to pipe which is read in my thread. Problem is that i have no idea how to save mp4 file. Which metadata i need to provide? Can i extract all of them from MediaRecorder. And how much bytes are provided for metadata. Possibly you have better idea how can i store that data as *.mp4 using some external library?

Thanks.

Comment: you just wanted to Record a Video in .MP4 format ?

Comment: No. I need to process data before save. Also i want to keep few last seconds in buffer and then save it when user click button.